# Why __get__ method is not called for instance attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is this code:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x

  def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
    print("__get__")
    return self.x

  def __set__(self, obj, value):
    pass

class B:
  a_oc = A(44)
  def __init__(self, y):
    self.a_ob = A(y)

b = B(3)
print(b.a_oc) # class attribute called __get__
print(b.a_ob) # __get__ not called
```

For class attribute `__get__` is called, for instance attribute it is not. Why?

Comment: Are you sure? I just ran this code, and nowhere is `__get__` printed to my console.

Comment: I have tried it with Python 3.3 and it is

Comment: Ah, NM, I was able to duplicate this in Python 3.2, but not Python 2.7

Comment: For Python 2.x it can be made to work if you explicitly make the classes inherit from `object`, so that they are "new-style objects",  i.e.:  `class A(object):`  and `class B(object):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute lookup rule for the new type class(class in 3.x and class inherits from object in 2.x) is, take `obj.attr`:

1. if the value is generated by Python, such as `__hash__`, return it
2. lookup in `obj.__class__.__dict__`, if it exists and there exists `__get__`, return the result of `attr.__get__(obj, obj.__class__)`, if not, lookup in the parent class recursively.
3. lookup in `obj.__dict__`. If `obj` is an instance and the attr exists, return it, or next step. Else if the `obj` is a class, lookup in itself's, its parents' `__dict__`, if it is a descriptor, return `attr.__get__(None, obj.__class__)` or the attr itself.
4. lookup in `obj.__class__.__dict__`. If attr is a non-data descriptor, return the result of it. Else return the attr itself if it exists.
5. raise AttributeError

See you class:

```
>>> b.__class__
<class 'des.B'>
>>> b.__class__.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__init__': <function B.__init__ at 0x7f2dacb4e290>, '__doc__': None, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'B' objects>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'B' objects>, 'a_oc': <des.A object at 0x7f2dacb5de50>, '__module__': 'des', '__qualname__': 'B'})
>>> 
>>> b.__dict__
{'a_ob': <des.A object at 0x7f2dacb5df10>}
>>>
```

`b.a_oc` fits step 2 and `b.a_ob` fits step3. I put your code in module `des`.

Comment: The order of lookup rules you post directly conflicts with your first paragraph.

Comment: Where does the conflicts lie?@Marcin

Comment: The first paragraph implies that presence in the instance `__dict__` will preempt a call to `__get__`, but you say `__get__` is called first. Clarification is required. Also, your first rule is vague to the point of being meaningless. Finally, please specify the source of these rules, and whether this applies only to Python 3.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English I can not understand the first two points. What's the difference of *preempt a call to __get__* and why the first rule is meaningless? @Marcin

Comment: "it is in `b.__dict__`, the `__get__` won't be called" BUT that is step 3 in your list, while checking `__get__` is step 2.

Comment: ...What I mean is once you are in step 3 and the attr is found, the `__get__` won't be called. I hard to say. I am quite sorry but I am not an English native. I will think and reorganize my words.@Marcin